# How to Undeprecate Facebook Code

Tags: android, facebook, deprecated

Could someone please help me undeprecate this bit of code?
This is the example give from Facebook (on how to connect to a FB account - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ ), however the marked line:

```
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
```

is deprecated. I tried to replace it with:

```
    Request.newMeRequest( session, callback, executeAsync() );
```

However, the code is nested so confusingly that it messes it all up. I would appreciate any help you could give as I've been at this all day.

```
// start Facebook Login
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

  // callback when session changes state
  @Override
  public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {

      // make request to the /me API
      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() { // *DEPRECATED

        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
          if (user != null) {
            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

}

Regards

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Replace your `Request.executeMeRequestAsync` with:

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

  // callback after Graph API response with user object
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    if (user != null) {
      TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
      welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
    }
  }
}).executeAsync();
```

i.e. Nothing changes except you're calling a slightly different method and putting `.executeAsync()` at the end.